# ORDER BY performance impact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. We have a table that specifies the incoming requests to be processed. Some of the columns are (total columns are 10),

```
requestId
requestStatus (Enum - Processed, NotProcessed, Failed, etc)
requestedTime
requestCompletionTime
```

The query to pick the new requests is

```
select top 10000 
from RequestProcessingTable 
where requestStatus = 'NotProcessed' 
order by requestId
```

The total number of rows in this table is 300 million.

We have 2 indexes, one clustered (`requestId` - primary key of this table) and one non-clustered (`requestStatus`).

Since we want to process the requests based on the `requestId` we need to do the `order by`. When we introduce the order by it is taking 3 times more time to select. Is there a best way to create indexes or do it in a different approach so that the performance of the SQL query can be improved.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you share the execution plan of the query?

Comment: Also include what you're selecting from the table. Is it just requestId or something else too

Answer (score 1):

Create a filtered index on `requestId` with the predicate `where requestStatus = 'NotProcessed'`. The optimiser is likely to favour this as long as the query conditions exactly match the index definition.

It may help to use a small tinyint for the status instead of a longer character string. There will be more rows per data page and less IO.

Answer (score 0):

**Share the execution plan**, like @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ said.

I think you can improve the performance of this query by creating a nonclustered index on requestStatus, requestId.

However: the fact that you are not specifying the column list (I'm guessing SELECT *) may change the plan by introducing Key Lookup or Clustered Index Scan (probably CIS on such a big table). If Clustered Index Scan is inserted to compensate for the lookup, the nonclustered index will not be helpful.

I can answer the question more precisely if you update the question with the plan.